# How to aggregate the sum of a class model field in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I've been attempting unsuccessfully to show the `total_net_interest` on my dashboard. I think there is a problem with my strategy. Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

**Model**

```
class Investment(models.Model):

    PLAN_CHOICES = (
        ("Basic - Daily 2% for 182 Days", "Basic - Daily 2% for 182 Days"),
        ("Premium - Daily 4% for 365 Days", "Premium - Daily 4% for 365 Days"),
    )
    plan = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PLAN_CHOICES, null=True)
    principal_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    investment_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)



    def daily_interest(self):
        if self.plan == "Basic - Daily 2% for 182 Days":
            return self.principal_amount * 365 * 0.02/2/182
        else:
            return self.principal_amount * 365 * 0.04/365 
    

    def net_interest(self):
        if self.plan == "Basic - Daily 2% for 182 Days":
            return self.principal_amount * 365 * 0.02/2
        else:
            return self.principal_amount * 365 * 0.04

    def total_net_interest(self):
        return self.Investment.aggregate(total_net_interest=Sum('net_interest'))['total_net_interest']
```

Comment: you want it from all Investment objects in database? first of all you canot query db on model functions those "fields" are not store in database.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, you can't aggregate using a model method - however, you could add `net_interest` to the queryset using annotation and then aggregate the annotated field.

[Django .aggregate() on .annotate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984711/django-aggregate-on-annotate)

You will likely need to use `Case` and `When` to apply your logic from that method.

As an aside, your model `PLAN_CHOICES` has both values copied, a better way of writing this would be something like this:

```py
PLAN_BASIC = "basic"
PLAN_PREMIUM = "premium"

PLAN_CHOICES = (
        (PLAN_BASIC, "Basic - Daily 2% for 182 Days"),
        (PLAN_PREMIUM, "Premium - Daily 4% for 365 Days")
)
```

This means that only "basic" and "premium" are stored in the database, but it will still show the verbose strings that you have entered. You can then do something like `Investment.PLAN_BASIC` or `self.PLAN_BASIC`, depending on the context, to ensure you aren't hard coding strings in multiple places.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `annotate` the interests in a queryset to aggregate on this annotations:

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, FloatField, Q, Sum, When

total = (Investment
         .objects
         .annotate(net=Case(When(Q(plan='Basic - Daily 2% for 182 Days'),
                                 then=F('principal_amount') * 365 * 0.01),
                            default=F('principal_amount') * 365 * 0.04,
                            output_field=FloatField))
         .aggregate(total=Sum('net')))['total']
```